# ModelBuilder inline variable does not change consecutively when iterating raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, iterator

I am trying to create a model in ModelBuilder (ArcMap 10.2.2), where there is an iteration through rasters in a workspace, each raster is run through a formula in raster calculator and where the output name is dependent on the raster name. As you can see in the picture, I have put an invariable output name %Name%, which should change with each iteration, with a new name coming from the new raster. This does not work however, only the first **two** iterations change the name, then all following iterations uses the **first** created namespace.

E.g.: If the raster file names are 'a' through 'c', the model will create raster a and b and then overwrite all following raster onto 'a' namespace, overwriting the data.

I have also tried using the %n% and %i% variables, with the same result.

I have put all rasters in a workspace (geodatabase) that is another than the the currently active one, using ArcCatalog Import-->Raster Datasets... in ArcMap window. The raster file names does only have text and numbers, no spaces or special characters.

[image: Faulty model]
*Model created in the ArcMap modelbuilder. There are so many arrows pointing to raster calculator because their values are used multiple times in the formula*

**Add.The problem with the model is that the generic variable "Workspace" don't work this way, see solution below**

This post seems to have a somewhat similar problem, although it has not been resolved: [Why does inline variable output overwrite occurs with Reorder fields tool?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63370/why-does-inline-variable-output-overwrite-occurs-with-reorder-fields-tool)

- I have also tried to set 'Name' as a precondition for Raster calculator.
- I have been trying both running raster sets from Workspace (default and other geodatabase (gdb)) and from a Raster catalog, same results.
- This happens even if I use other tools such as Clip, with Workspace as input for rasters.

I am using the following paths:

**input:** E:\kaosmapp\Magdalena Bulks\NDVI calc\NDVI_images
or E:\kaosmapp\Magdalena Bulks\NDVI calc\NDVI_calc.gdb (tried both)

**output:** E:\kaosmapp\Magdalena Bulks\NDVI calc\output\%Name%.tif

It gives the same result regardless if I add .tif or not for output file.

Comment: Two tricks: 1.Make sure you use the correct case for the inline variable - here %Name% and not %name% - this seems to be OK from your screenshot - 2. Try setting 'Name' as precondition for the Raster Calculator tool. I've had such issues with 10.0, don't know if they still occur in 10.2.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Sadly, it did not do the trick.

I made sure the I was using %Name% and also tried %i% and %n% namespaces and tried adding precondition of 'Name'. After that I also tried adding precondition of 'Raster' and 'Workspace'. 

Still the same problem, file 'a' and file 'b' are created, then all files are written to 'a'

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us what your raster calculator expression is?

Comment: Hi Hornbydd, This happens regardless of the raster calculator expression (for example ' "Raster"+1' ) and even with other tools such as e.g. Clip.

Comment: Ok, show us what the full paths are for your inputs and outputs.

Comment: Have you saved your model in a toolbox? Also, save your workspace and everything and reboot your computer and try again.

Comment: I realize it could be a big step if you've not done any programming before, but it seems to me that this is easier to solve if you convert your model to a Python script tool instead. Maybe it is because I don't fully understand what each box in modelbuilder does, but I think it is easier to see what is happening in a script and to run sections of it.

Comment: Hornbydd, I have updated my question with the following information: I am using the following paths:
input: E:\kaosmapp\Magdalena Bulks\NDVI calc\NDVI_images
or E:\kaosmapp\Magdalena Bulks\NDVI calc\NDVI_calc.gdb (tried both)
output: E:\kaosmapp\Magdalena Bulks\NDVI calc\output\%Name%.tif
It gives the same result regardless if I add .tif or not for output file.

Comment: Mace, The model is saved in a toolbox, everything is saved and rebooted without change in results.

Comment: It is very difficult if not impossible to troubleshoot a model like this unless you can give us a link to the toolbox and say 2 of your raster to download.

Comment: Have to agree with @Ifyoudonotknow-justGIS we really need to see the model as currently everything you have done seems OK to me? Are you putting some sort of wild card filter in the iterator?

Comment: Works fine for me on 10.3.1. Might be a long-shot but have you tried writing to in_memory and then copying it? (for example using Raster To Other Format)

Comment: Thank you for your help everybody. I have been helped to the solution you can see above in the updated post.

Comment: At the moment you have included bot the question and answer within the area reserved for your question.  Would you be able to cut/paste (and tidy) to format this content as a question and an answer, please?  By doing that you will not only be conforming to our Q&A format, but you may well benefit reputation-wise and be able to unlock more of the site functionality sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer (by the asker) has been moved from within the question to conform to the Q&A format of this site.

---

To make the iteration work, I had to create a geodatabase and import all rasters I wanted to manipulate. Then I could click''n'drag the gdb into the model. By setting the gdb as a 'Model parameter' the model can be feeded with any other geodatabase and saved into any folder or geodatabase.

However, if a generic variable 'Workspace' is created, linked to an iteration and then feeded with the same geodatabase, my problem described above will occur.

[image: Working model]
*Working model with geodatabase click'n'dragged into model*